# Flutter からネイティブの電話機能を呼び出して自動で発信するには？

Tags: flutter, dart

現在Flutterでスマホアプリ開発をしています。
その中で、作成しているアプリから電話アプリへ画面遷移して、電話番号入力欄にあらかじめアプリ側で指定した番号が入力されることが確認できました。

ですが、自動で発信というところまで至っていません。
自動で発信するという機能は実装可能でしょうか、もし可能であれば参考文献やソースコードなどをいただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

これらのサイトを見ました：

https://medium.com/flutter-community/sms-from-flutter-9caefd0d0dd4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826922/how-to-send-sms-automatically-in-flutter

二番目のは英語のスタックオーバーフローのページです、
彼がサンプルを作ってくれたらしいです、詳しくは見ていないですが、そちらのリンクを貼ります：
https://github.com/rodrigoc85/flutter-sms-dispatcher

このような機能を実装しようとする人は少ないと思いますが、
このリポジトリを真似したら実現できるかもしれません。

以上